# Is there a Live Disk or Live Flash Drive for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, usb-flash-drive, livecd

I have tried different Linux flavors through Live Disks and I do like using that as one of privacy measures. I did some looking into obtaining Live Disk of Mac OS X but could not find one. Some people say it is impossible to make one but is it?

If any part of the OS or the apps it's running requires write access, it may crash or refuse to work. I understand that so if neither CD nor DVD(DL) is an option what about USB flash drive?

Comment: Pretty sure its impossible.

Comment: Did you ever get something working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple Google search for `mac OS X live DVD` yields:

https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/OSx86#Live_DVD

the creation of such a live DVD should only be legal if you own a copy of the respective OS. there are discussions on several boards that this live DVD works on macs and on hackintosh-PCs (normal computers).

And to the write issue: thats true, but using a RAMdisk (write to RAM instead of harddisk or readonly-media) solves this problem.

just follow the links below the wikipedia article, they should give you more than enough information I guess.